# Flutter: 2.2.3 - How to solve the error: Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:XYZ

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

When I create a clean flutter project(flutter create proj_name) Then I try run it in debug mode from vs-code on a real device android 5.1.1 and it starts and works fine for the first time, but if i stop application and run it in debug mode again the following message like this results

[image: Error result image]

What helps to run in debug mode the application is restarting the real smartphone so it will work until you stop the application and try to run in debug mode again.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can solve this?

[image: Result of the flutter doctor -v command image]

Comment: Make sure your firewall is not blocking the port. An antivirus may be blocking the process after the first run?

Comment: @JaffaKetchup, How can I check firewall, any suggestions?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @JaffaKetchup, Windows 10

Comment: @JaffaKetchup, When I ran applications with sdk from flutter 1.26 it worked perfectly, but after migration to flutter 2.2.3 even the clean project this error occurs on the second start.

Comment: It probably isn't that then, sorry!

Comment: @JaffaKetchup, The application also runs perfectly if SDK 29 is on an emulator

Comment: Android 5.1.1 is an old Android version API level 22. I'm not sure why it would work the first time and not after that, but there's probably an incompatible version somewhere causing the error?

Comment: @JaffaKetchup, What might be incompatible if none of the additional packages were added in .yaml?Maybe flutter 2.2.3 is incompatible to run debug without problems with android 5.1.1 but I sincerely doubt it.

Comment: @JaffaKetchup, I tried to run in debug mode and stop and run again project that has same problem, so android 5.1 with sdk 22 on emulator it works fine.

Comment: @JaffaKetchup, Do you know what it can be? Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: @JaffaKetchup,I noticed that when the error occurs it tries to connect for the second time using the http protocol ("http://127.0.0.1:XYZ"), but when the first time it tries to connect and connects successfully it uses websockets ("ws://127.0 .0.1:xyz"), do you know why this could happen?

Comment: Sorry, really not sure, maybe there's some messed up config somewhere, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

The error points out that it has issues connecting to the Android emulator. Checking the `flutter doctor` logs, the emulator doesn't seem to appear. Try restarting the emulator using cold boot. Open the Android Device Manager and click on `Cold Boot Now` on the emulated device. Then run `flutter doctor --verbose` to check if the emulator can now be seen in the list of connected devices.

[image: Android Device Manager]

Answer (score 0):

A YouTube video said choose an older emulator and demonstrated the difference - it worked.

I followed the video's example and it worked.

What I did specifically was, set up a new Android emulator, and in the process I downloaded a lower API number.  On this occasion I chose API 28 whereas I had been using API 33.

[image]